# Selecting a generated id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html element like this:

```
<div id="myelement_9082173219731721923">
```

I want to add a class to this element to select it with css.
It is loaded after the other stuff on the site, because it´s generated by an external javascript.
That´s why I tried:

```
$('[id^="myelement_"]').load(function()
{
    alert("im here");
    $('[id^="myelement_"]').addClass('myclass');
});
```

But it doesn´t reach the alert. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work, `load` on the `div` element will never happen. Use a DOM change listener instead. And you don't need the quotes around the `id` selector. It is not wrong, but not a must have.

```
$("body").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    $('[id^="myelement_"]').addClass('myclass');
});
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/uLcb1vqo/1/)**

You should change `body` to the most smallest selector of your DOM, where the `div#myelement_` will be appear. And if it happens only one time, change `on` to `one`. Then the listener disables itself and will not run constantly on changes.

Comment: I want to execute the function if just this element has loaded, not if the other is loaded, because just this element is loaded after $(function()

Comment: What is inside the `div` that could be loaded? Images can be loaded, videos can be loaded, but what you are waiting for?

Comment: The element doesn´t exist already if you try to modify it on $(function().
It is loaded from an external javascript. That´s why it wont work

Comment: Okay, I've changed my answer @ElDiabolo. You can't not wait for `load`, this is never happen. You can use a DOM change event instead.

Comment: Ideally, you should use the DOM change event to look for the element, and if it exists then add the class and turn the event handler off, or this will fire every single time anything changes in the DOM.

Comment: Correct @Archer. I've put this in the Answer too. In this case he should use `one`.

Comment: $("body").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function()
is never executed... I tried $('[id^="myelement_"]').ready(function() also but it is definitly not loaded before.

Comment: Maybe you listener registration is too late and the element already exists?! Hard to say without seeing the whole code...